# Vue countdown timer prints out on console.log but don't get passed on as data

Tags: vue.js, momentjs, countdowntimer

I am using `moment js` to countdown the time as 10,9,8,7,6 . It successfully counts down time on `console.log` but I am not able to pass that as a data.

Below is my code on jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/817bqn52/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function inside `setInterval` to an arrow functions, in order to read `this` as the Vue component:

```
setInterval(() => {
      duration.subtract(interval, "milliseconds"); //using momentjs substract function
      this.countdownTimer = moment(duration.asMilliseconds()).format('s'); 
      console.log(moment(duration.asMilliseconds()).format('s'));
      /* countdown timer works for console.log */
}, interval );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `this` in the setInterval handler by default points to the window object. You could change this by adding `.bind(this)` to the function, or using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Update JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qg4863tv

Read more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#The_this_problem